# sorting an associative array by boolean field

Tags: php, sorting

`$list` is populated thusly: -

```
$list[$i++] = array(
    "date" => $date,
    "desc" => $desc,
    "priority" => $priority
);
```

`$priority` is set to `TRUE` if it matches some criteria.

I'd like the `$list` to be sorted with rows that have a priority `TRUE` at the top.

The list is already sorted by date which I wish to preserve.

Comment: OK, so do it. `usort` takes a custom sorting function, and the documentation explains how to use it. You have not specified a question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In PHP>=5.3

```
usort ($array, function ($left, $right) {
    return $left['priority'] - $right['priority'];
});
```

Or in earlier version

```
function cmp($left, $right) {
    return $left['priority'] - $right['priority'];
}
usort($array, 'cmp');
```

Or use [create_function()](http://php.net/create-function) (also for version < 5.3)

```
usort ($array, create_function('$left,$right', 'return $left[\'priority\'] - $right[\'priority\'];'));
```

This works, because `(int) true === 1` and `(int) false === 0`

```
true - true == 0
true - false == 1
false - true == -1
false - false == 0
```

Comment: The only thing is that if you actually want to have `TRUE` values at the top you have to swap `$left` and `$right`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [usort](https://www.php.net/usort) and supply your own sort function describing whether true is greater then false or the other way around.

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return ($a['priority'] > $b['priority']) ? 1 : -1;
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```

if you want to change the stability of the sort, where elements are sorted if they have the same priority value, then just modify the cmp function.

Answer (score 0):

use this function

```
function sort2d ($array, $index, $order='asc', $natsort=FALSE, $case_sensitive=FALSE)  
    { 
        if(is_array($array) && count($array)>0)  
        { 
           foreach(array_keys($array) as $key)  
               $temp[$key]=$array[$key][$index]; 
               if(!$natsort)  
                   ($order=='asc')? asort($temp) : arsort($temp); 
              else  
              { 
                 ($case_sensitive)? natsort($temp) : natcasesort($temp); 
                 if($order!='asc')  
                     $temp=array_reverse($temp,TRUE); 
           } 
           foreach(array_keys($temp) as $key)  
               (is_numeric($key))? $sorted[]=$array[$key] : $sorted[$key]=$array[$key]; 
           return $sorted; 
      } 
      return $array; 
    }
```

and call

> sort2d ($list, $priority);

Comment: The `Reference` link is dead...

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays in PHP you could use arrow function syntax (PHP >=7.4) and the [spaceship operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) `<=>` (PHP >=7.0)

```php
usort ($list, static fn (array $a, array $b): int => (int)$b['priority'] <=> (int)$a['priority']);
```

Try it on: https://3v4l.org/Cuvkl