# Get value from array by matching values

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to get the value **assetid** from a json print by matching the values **classid** and **instanceid** with another json print.

Let me make it more clear.

I've tried different things but I just don't know where to start. It doesn't give me any results at all.

This is the case.

This is the **first** json print.

```
[22] => Array (
    [appid] => 730
    [contextid] => 2
    [assetid] => 15722336716
    [classid] => 310776570
    [instanceid] => 302028390
    [amount] => 1 
  )
```

As you can see, it contains a value called **assetid** which I need to get.

This is the **second** json print.

```
[6] => Array (
    [appid] => 730
    [classid] => 310776570
    [instanceid] => 302028390
    [currency] => 0
  )
```

The classid and instanceid is matching, but I need to get the assetid from the first json print by matching the classid and instanceid from the second json print.

This is what my code currently looks like, which ONLY prints out the **second** json print.

```
if(isset($inventories['descriptions'])) {
    foreach($inventories['descriptions'] as $key => $description) {
        //Testing                               
        $inv = $inventories['assets'][$description['classid'].'_'.$description['instanceid'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your question as follows: Given a list of JSON objects (you call them prints), you want to assign `assetid`values to those who don't have ones yet, based on other objects who have one and match the `classid` and `instanceid` fields.

One approach to solve this problem is:

- Sort your JSON objects, such that those that have an `assetid` field come first. This might happen when you retrieve the data (some API query?), or later using e.g. [usort()](https://www.php.net/usort)
- Initialize an empty array, let's call it `assetids`. This will map `classid_instanceid` pairs (string concatenation, as in your code) to asset IDs later.
- Iterate through the list of JSON objects. For each of those objects:

  - If it does have an `assetid` field: Save it together with a concatenation of `classid` and `instanceid` as key in `assetids`
  - If it does *not* have an `assetid` field: Check the `assetids` array for the concatenation of `classid` and `instanceid`.

    - If it exists, you have the matching `assetid`.
    - If not, a matching `assetid` does not exist.

A PHP implementation might look like this (I used arrays instead of JSON objects for simplicity):

```php
// Some example data
$data = Array(
    Array (
        "name" => "a",
        "assetid" => 100,
        "classid" => 1,
        "instanceid" => 1,
    ),
    Array (
        "name" => "b",
        "classid" => 2,
        "instanceid" => 1,
    ),
    Array (
        "name" => "c",
        "classid" => 1,
        "instanceid" => 1,
    ),
    Array (
        "name" => "d",
        "classid" => 3,
        "instanceid" => 1,
    ),
    Array (
        "name" => "e",
        "assetid" => 200,
        "classid" => 2,
        "instanceid" => 1,
    )
);

// Make sure entries with "assetid" field come first
// See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5897975/8528014
usort($data, function ($a, $b)
{
    return isset($b['assetid']) - isset($a['assetid']);
});

// Determine assetids
$assetids = Array();
foreach($data as $obj)
{
    if(isset($obj['assetid']))
    {
        $key = $obj['classid'].'_'.$obj['instanceid'];
        $assetid = $obj['assetid'];
        $assetids[$key] = $assetid;
        echo "Object ".$obj['name']." has assetid $assetid\n";
    }
    else
    {
        $key = $obj['classid'].'_'.$obj['instanceid'];
        if(!isset($assetids[$key]))
            echo "Could not find assetid for object ".$obj['name']."\n";
        else
        {
            $assetid = $assetids[$key];
            echo "Object ".$obj['name']." has assetid $assetid\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Object a has assetid 100
Object e has assetid 200
Object b has assetid 200
Object c has assetid 100
Could not find assetid for object d
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand what your points is, the second one is best for me I think. However, can you please provide me with an example code of which I can try to apply to it?

Comment: I just added a simplified example which you only need to slightly adjust to fit into your code base (replace arrays by JSON objects, replace the `name` field by your payload like `appid` and `amount`).